# How to pass parameter value from pipeline to others in Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to define parameter in ADF only once since I wisht overwrite parameter in DevOps only once for simplicity.

I have main pipeline with parameter "Database", which has value "DB1".

I'm calling Execute Pipeline and I would like to pass DatabaseName to the child pipeline.
Parameter setting of Execute Pipeline is "Database", which has value ""

Child pipeline parameter has is "Database", which has value "".
I have Lookup Activity, which make Query with parameter "Database"

When I execute main pipeline I get error. I see that Lookup used "Database", which has value "".

How to pass parameter value from pipeline to others?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create parameter in child pipeline and pass the parameter to the dataset property in lookup activity.

**Child pipeline:**

1. Add dataset parameter for the database name

[image]

2. Create the child pipeline parameter.

[image]

3. Pass the child pipeline parameter to the lookup activity dataset properties.

[image]

**Master pipeline:**

4. Create Master pipeline parameter.

[image]

5. In Execute pipeline activity settings, when you select child pipeline, you will see the child parameter under Parameters.
6. Pass the Master pipeline parameter in child parameter value as shown below.

[image]